# Header elements [logo and menu] changes position according to the screen resolution

Tags: html, css

I have this site of mine [www.virtualcloudguru.com](http://www.virtualcloudguru.com). Now the problem here is the header (The logo and the menu). I've defined a fixed 100px padding for both logo and menu but it will shift left/right if the screen resolution changes.

Now there are 2 ways

1. Make both of them align in the center of the screen
2. Make the 2 elements change position according to the screen resolution.

I've copied [the code in **jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uXXcY/). Although not complete

Comment: What is the question? Are you trying to center the header?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Couldn't you get the question?

Comment: yeah thats the last option . You can give me the solution for that also. Thanks

Comment: @user1745857 Give a width for `#header`. Remove the padding for the `a`. Check my CSS.

Comment: @user1745857 And yeah, the fiddle is of no use. `:P` I solved with the help of the link you gave!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make elements change position according to screen resolution, you can use CSS media queries. Here's an example that will work with your page:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #header .top-logo, #header ul {
        padding-left: 0;
    }
}
```

You can think of the `@media` line as similar to an "if" statement for CSS. In this case, it's saying if the media is a screen (i.e. not print, etc.) and has a maximum width of 600 pixels, make the left padding 0 for the logo and list in the header.

In other words, any CSS rules within this `@media` section are only effective when the browser's visible window width is 600 pixels or less, in which case they override any previous CSS rules.

Add this to the end of your CSS and trying narrowing the browser's window to see the effect.

EDIT: I forgot to add that it's OK to have more than one `@media` section. For example, you could add a second section with `max-width: 480px` (or similar) containing rules for smaller screens.

EDIT 2: Centering the logo and menu

The logo has a fixed width so we can make it a block element and use `margin: 0 auto`, like this:

```
#header .top-logo {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 425px;
}
```

Remember to remove your existing `float: left`.

For the menu, this is just text so we can use `text-align: center`. Again, remember to remove your existing `float: left` on the li elements — we'll use `display: inline` instead.

```
#header ul {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#header ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Please double-check this cross-browser before implementing, by the way.

Comment: thanks tagwa. it worked like a charm. Its too much too ask but can you also tell me how to center both the logo and the menu? Thanks

Comment: Lol, this doesn't even need `@media` queries. Plus this won't work in IE!

Comment: You're right, it could be done without media queries but I believe this is a more flexible solution long-term. As for IE, media queries are supported in IE9 and above. For me, this is fine because of the relative lack of small screen devices using IE up to version 8. Of course, there are JS libraries to add media query support if it's really deemed necessary.

Comment: @user1745857 Added code for centering the logo and menu to the answer.

Comment: Boss, you forgot that my office system uses `IE 6` in a resolution of `640 x 480`! Just saying! :)

Comment: That's still above the 600px used in the answer so it wouldn't be affected, but for argument's sake, if it's felt necessary to support smaller screen devices than that, running IE up to version 8, then JS libraries such as https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond do a good job.

Answer (score 1):

#### Please use this CSS

```
#header {
    width: 1130px;
    padding: 0;
}

#header .top-logo {
    padding: 0;
}
```

#### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: praveen thanks for the reply . can you also tell me how to center both the logo and the menu on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the header to always stay in the same position relative to the body of the page, then place the two into a common div, and apply the width: and margin: properties that you would have applied to the body, to that container.

You can also use the `body` element as the common container and apply width and margin to that too, as an alternative.